# What game does John Buckley mention in S06E09?

Tags: plot-explanation, numb3rs

On season 6 episode 9 of [*Numb3rs*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0433309/) John Buckley mentions a game that he played in prison. What was the game that he mentioned, and is it a real game?

Comment: This is the western version of the game. http://www.neok12.com/games/hare-hounds/hare-hounds.htm

Comment: There is an exciting variation available for android too https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.randomizerapps.millitaire

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to this [transcript](http://www.livedash.com/transcript/numb3rs-%28con_job%29/7854/TNTP/Friday_October_15_2010/476899/), the game is called Jeu Militaire, also known as the [French Military Game](http://www.huffmancoding.com/code/fmg/index.html) thought it has nothing to do with France or the military. It is a strategy game that works like this:

> The game is played against the computer with the two players
>   alternating turns. You control the three black pieces while the
>   computer controls the remaining red piece. You always go first.
>
> The pieces move along the lines to the adjacent spots. The red
>   computer piece can move in any direction along those lines, while your
>   black pieces cannot go in a backward (downward) direction.
>
> To move, drag a black piece to valid adjacent location. You win the
>   game by trapping the computer where it cannot move within 20 turns. As
>   an example, if the black pieces were at the lower left, middle, and
>   upper left spots and the red piece was trapped at the middle left, you
>   would win.
>
> The computer wins by reaching the very bottom, where it cannot be
>   caught.

[image]

There appears to be a downloadable [freeware version](http://hem.passagen.se/melki9/haregames.htm) called Hare - it requires additional downloads, so I have not tested it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a framed game with Union Generals in each corner called Militaire. It has 6 circles of peg-holes and Ironclad ships battling in the center. Manufactured by Newland, Detroit. N.D.